# How To Search For a Green Jumper?

Tags: image, image-processing

I was wondering how a Google image search for something like a 'green jumper' actually works? How does the system know that the image contains a jumper shape that is of the color green?

I'm thinking it uses a sobel or Hough transform then some sort of colour recognition. Then these values are somehow attached to the image in the database?

Any insight would be helpful. Need not necessarily be related to Google, just image search in general.

Comment: Have look at this [DSP question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/5995/what-algorithm-does-google-use-for-its-search-by-image-site/6008#6008)

Answer (score 1):

The majority of the information used for the basic google image search is not the image *content*, but the metainformation. Metainformation is (...a word with 15 letters) ... the file name of the image file, the contents of the `alt` attribute that is contained in the HML `<img ...>` tag, and possibly other (text) content that is mentioned on the same site as the image. For example, when you search for "green jumper", you'll find many green sweatshirts, but also some images of spiders, namely of a species that is referred to as [Green Jumping Spider, or "Green Jumper"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mopsus_%28spider%29).

However, some information is obviously extracted from the image content even for the simple image search. For example, the "main color" of the image. But this information is comparatively trivial to extract - it's just the color of the image when it is smoothly scaled down to have a size of 1x1 pixels.

Going beyond that, Google has made some advances in the area of "image recognition" in the last few years. There is a lot of research going on. One intermediate step was the [Content-based image retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-based_image_retrieval) in form of the "Similar Image Search". This has recently been driven further in the form of feature extraction. An entry point containing several links to the developments may be the article about [Google Image Swirl](http://googleresearch.blogspot.de/2009/11/explore-images-with-google-image-swirl.html), where each linked site in turn contains links to scientific publications in the respective area.

Comment: Good answer, thank you, but I'm looking for more than just google's alt tag method of image search.

Comment: @BenjaminFranklin Many of them are summarized in the last link, and in the sites referenced from there, ... but sorry, I can't tell say more about this ATM

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how google exactly does it, but [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/44530222/Image-Recognition-in-Artificial-Intelligence) is a good introduction.